# How to use same method but to call different methods in response every time?

Tags: angular

I have method `InfoDetails();` I need to call that method in different methods but in response for that different methods to call other methods. So want i want is something like this:

```
InfoDetails(methodName){
  this.methodName(params);
}
```

Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: please give a more detailed example . this is very confusing

Comment: `window[methodName]();` Should work but its global. A different solution would be to store your methods in an object an then simply `objname[methodName]();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understand you currctly and im not sure i am. 
you can do somthing like this

```js
InfoDetails = function(methodName){
  return window[methodName](arguments)
}

mymethod1 = function(params){
     return 'mymethod1'
}
mymethod2 = function(params){
      return 'mymethod2'
}
console.log(InfoDetails('mymethod1'))
console.log(InfoDetails('mymethod2'))


//or its the function own method
InfoDetails = function(methodName){
  return this[methodName](arguments)
}

InfoDetails.prototype.mymethod1 = function(params){
     return 'mymethod1'
}
InfoDetails.prototype.mymethod2 = function(params){
      return 'mymethod2'
}
var a =  InfoDetails('mymethod1')
console.log(a)
```

Comment: If you now explain whats the positive/negative of both solutions its the perfect answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the method passed as parameter but I would check if it’s of the type function just to be a bit more defensive

```
InfoDetails(methodName, params){
    if(typeof methodName === ‘function’){
       methodName(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to mention, this way he don´t pass the methodName he passes the method itself. So calling the function like `InfoDetail("SomeMethodname", "parameters")` wouldn´t work he would have to call `InfoDetails(someMethod(), "params")` or I´m wrong ?

Comment: Good point. You might be right. The question was not very clear though. Not much detail on the intention